# What Is The SQL Query For Creating a Pivot Table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

i am trying to create a SQL query in order to create a pivot table, and my data is on a PostgreSQL database.

as i understand there are 4 elements involved in creating a pivot table

1) row group

2) column group

3) measure group

4) a function (e.g : Max)

and i think `CASE ... WHEN` columns are playing a role in creating a pivot (crosstab) query.

so with these elements, what the corresponding SQL Query will look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert row data into columns, then you can use an aggregate function along with a CASE expression.

Let's say your data is similar to the following:

```
create table yourtable
(
  id int,
  name varchar(50),
  amount decimal (10,2)
);

insert into yourtable
select 1, 'Jim', 50.00 union all
select 2, 'Bob', 150.00 union all
select 3, 'Blah', 500.00;
```

And you want to convert the names into columns, then you could use a basic query similar to the following to get the result:

```
select
  sum(case when name = 'Jim' then amount else 0 end) as Jim,
  sum(case when name = 'Bob' then amount else 0 end) as Bob,
  sum(case when name = 'Blah' then amount else 0 end) as Blah
from yourtable
```

This would give you a result of:

```
| Jim    | Bob    | Blah   |
| 50.00  | 150.00 | 500.00 |
```

Comment: thanks. would you answer using terms described in my question? i mean 'measure group , column group and row group' ?